# Hide icon on hover in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of html which looks like this

```
<div>
    <i onclick="delete()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <object style="height:100%; width:100%;" data="https://example.com/static/img/4510119851.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

Here I have an svg image which I show in `object` tag and a `cross` icon. Now I want the icon to only show up when I hover on the image.

I tried changing the `css` like this

```
object i {
        display: none;
}

object:hover i {
        display: block;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey, you can't `object:hover i` because i is not child of object..

Answer (score 2):

The `i` element is a sibling of `object`, not it's child . You should select it like this :

```
object ~ i {
        display: none;
}

object:hover ~ i {
        display: block;
}
```

Updated : Because `i` is the `object` 's previous sibling, and for now there is no selector for previous sibling.  I suggest to move your `i` to after `object` and hack it's positioning with `position: absolute`.

```css
/*Positioning*/
.icon {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative
}

.img {
  background: green;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

/*The sibling selector*/

.img:hover ~ .icon {
 display: block;
}
.img ~ .icon {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent"> 
  <div class = "img"> Hover Me</div>
  <div class = "icon"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it will only work if `i` is the next sibling of `object.`

Comment: @Ethan sorry but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @SouvikRay Yeah, since it a previous sibling, and for now there is no selector for previous sibling. I suggest that you move the `i` element to after `object` and work around positioning with `position: absolute`